# Tcl parsing: puzzled by quotes inside brackets

Tags: parsing, tcl

This is a contrived example, I created it by reducing my problem to the most simple case possible:

```
tcl> puts "aaa [puts \"bbb\"]"
"bbb"
aaa
```

It's natural that `"bbb"` is output first, the code in `[ ]` is evaluated prior to the outer command. What puzzles me, however, are those quotation marks.

The following code does what I want:

```
tcl> puts "aaa [puts "bbb"]"
bbb
aaa
```

Probably I'm not the only one whose eyes got hurt by those unescaped inner quotes. I know there are brackets, they're pretty and they're doing their job well, but I would still expect Tcl to find the end of the string first and only then recurse into it to expand its contents. Could someone kindly elaborate?

Comment: It's not really a contrived example, but rather a good reduction of the problem. Hopefully the issue is clearer now and you can start thinking about why `puts "aaa [puts bbb]"` and `puts aaa[puts bbb]` work too ;) It's the Tcl syntax paradox: the syntax is simple and extremely regular, which means that the freedom to form expressions, sometimes quite unfathomable, is greater than in many other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TCL manpage starts with a concise definition of the TCL syntax. Excerpt:

> [4] Double quotes.
>
> > If the first character of a word is double-quote (“"”) then the word is terminated by the next double-quote character... Command substitution, variable substitution, and backslash substitution are performed on the characters between the quotes as described below.  The double-quotes are not retained as part of the word.
>
> [7] Command substitution.
>
> > If a word contains an open bracket (“[”) then Tcl performs command substitution.  To do this it invokes the Tcl interpreter recursively  to  process  the characters following the open bracket as a Tcl script.  The script may contain any number of commands and must be terminated by a close bracket (“]”).
>
> [11] Order of substitution.
>
> > Each character is processed exactly once by the Tcl interpreter as part of creating the words of a command... If command substitution occurs then the nested command is processed entirely by the  recursive  call  to  the  Tcl interpreter...

In short, TCL does a single scan, so the command substitution `[puts \"bbb\"]` is parsed, executed and substituted by a recursive call to the interpreter while the outer word is being scanned; consequently, <kbd>"</kbd> characters are not seen by the outer interpreter.